# How do i access vertex coordinates of an obj model in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, simulation, p5.js

I wanna be able to move around each individual vertex of an obj model that i imported into p5..so i wanna be able to access the coordinates of each individual vertex. Is this possible to do??

I tried console logging the model and finding the coordinates there, but didnt find anything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `p5.Geometry` object has a `vertices` property which is a list of `p5.Vector` objects. You can modify these vertices, however when you make changes you also need to update the `gid` property to invalidate cached buffers based on the original list. Also this only allows you to modify existing triangles, adding and removing triangles is more complicated and involves the `vertexNormals` and `faces` properties as well.

```js
//draw a spinning teapot
let teapot;
let version = 0;

function preload() {
  // Load model with normalize parameter set to true
  teapot = loadModel('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/teapot.obj', true);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400, WEBGL);
  describe('Vertically rotating 3-d teapot with red, green and blue gradient. Double click to mutate vertices.');
}

function doubleClicked() {
  // randomly translate the vertices.
  for (const v of teapot.vertices) {
    v.x *= random(0.95, 1.05);
    v.y *= random(0.95, 1.05);
    v.z *= random(0.95, 1.05);
  }

  teapot.computeNormals();
  
  // Update the geometry id so that the vertex buffer gets recreated
  // Without this p5.js will reused the cached vertex buffer.
  teapot.gid = `teapot-version-${version++}`;
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  scale(1.6); // Scaled to make model fit into canvas
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  normalMaterial(); // For effect
  model(teapot);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: More information on p5.Geometry: http://paulwheeler.us/articles/custom-3d-geometry-in-p5js/